# A better way than a switch case

Tags: php, laravel, switch-statement, coding-style

I have a method that utilizes switch - case blocks similar to the below chunk of code:

```
    switch ($totalMonthsFromImmigration) {
        case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 18:
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', null);
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', null);
            break;
        case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 30:
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', null);
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', null);
            break;
        case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 42:
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', null);
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', null);
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
            break;
    }
```

As it can be seen from the above example the cases make a similar things, and there's a little difference.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation? I don't really like the duplication of the code.

Comment: Why not set all three to null initially, then just generate the string `'immigrant_[X]'` in the switch to set the right one?

Comment: Note that `switch ($foo) case $foo < $bar:` doesn't work as you think it does. If you need non-equal comparisons, you should be using `if..else if..else`, not `switch`.

Comment: @deceze thanks! i'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set default value then add value based on condition

```
$this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', null);
$this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', null);
$this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', null);

switch ($totalMonthsFromImmigration) {
            case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 18:
                $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
                break;
            case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 30:
                $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
                break;
            case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 42:
                $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
                break;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way for doing this, try **IF** if you want to change from **Switch** case

```
if ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 18){
 $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
} else if ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 30) {
 $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
else if ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 42) {
 $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If calling the setter twice for the default values like @Jignesh Joisar is not desired:

```
$this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 18) ? $this->clauses->get('immigrant') : null);
$this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', ($totalMonthsFromImmigration > 18 && $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 30) ? $this->clauses->get('immigrant') : null);
$this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', ($totalMonthsFromImmigration > 30 && $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 42) ? $this->clauses->get('immigrant') : null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought there's a math formula to instead of using switch case or if else. But I didn't find one. This is my solution based on the answers I saw here:

```
    $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', null);
    $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', null);
    $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', null);

    if ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 18) {
        $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
    } else if ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 30) {
        $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
    } else if ($totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 42) {
        $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($totalMonthsFromImmigration) {
         case $totalMonthsFromImmigration <= 42:
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_1', $this->clauses->get('immigrant'));
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_2', null);
            $this->clauses->put('immigrant_3', null);
        break;
        default:
           echo "Your logic you want greeter then 42"
```

}